# Hyperledger fabric switching from levelDB to couchDB

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem switching from levelDB to couchDB as the state database. I'm using the test-network from the hyperledger sample repository and I have edited the `docker-compose-couch.yaml` file inside of the docker folder and the `core.yaml` file inside of the config folder.
These are all the changes that I made, but when I start the network it still uses leveldb.
`Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb'`


*core.yaml:*

```
ledger:

  blockchain:

  state:
    # stateDatabase - options are "goleveldb", "CouchDB"
    # goleveldb - default state database stored in goleveldb.
    # CouchDB - store state database in CouchDB
    stateDatabase: CouchDB
    # Limit on the number of records to return per query
    totalQueryLimit: 100000
    couchDBConfig:
       # It is recommended to run CouchDB on the same server as the peer, and
       # not map the CouchDB container port to a server port in docker-compose.
       # Otherwise proper security must be provided on the connection between
       # CouchDB client (on the peer) and server.
       couchDBAddress: 127.0.0.1:5984
       # This username must have read and write authority on CouchDB
       username: ${CouchDbUser}
       # The password is recommended to pass as an environment variable
       # during start up (eg CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD).
       # If it is stored here, the file must be access control protected
       # to prevent unintended users from discovering the password.
       password: ${CouchDbPw}
       # Number of retries for CouchDB errors
       maxRetries: 3
       # Number of retries for CouchDB errors during peer startup.
       # The delay between retries doubles for each attempt.
       # Default of 10 retries results in 11 attempts over 2 minutes.
       maxRetriesOnStartup: 10
       # CouchDB request timeout (unit: duration, e.g. 20s)
       requestTimeout: 35s
       internalQueryLimit: 1000
       maxBatchUpdateSize: 1000
       warmIndexesAfterNBlocks: 1
       createGlobalChangesDB: false
       cacheSize: 64
```

*docker-compose-couch.yaml:*

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

networks:
  test:

services:
  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: couchdb:3.1.1
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=${CouchDbUser}
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=${CouchDbPw}
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - test

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=${CouchDbUser}
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=${CouchDbPw}
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: couchdb:3.1.1
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=${CouchDbUser}
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=${CouchDbPw}
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "7984:5984"
    networks:
      - test

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    environment:
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=${CouchDbUser}
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=${CouchDbPw}
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1
```

The only docker containers that are running is one ordering node and two peer nodes.

**Edit:** I just did the same steps on a completly new test network and it's still using leveldb as the state database

```
Starting nodes with CLI timeout of '5' tries and CLI delay of '3' seconds and using database 'leveldb' with crypto from 'cryptogen'
LOCAL_VERSION=2.3.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=2.3.0
/run/media/jonas/DATA/hyperledger/network with couchdb/fabric-samples/bin/cryptogen
Generate certificates using cryptogen tool
Create Org1 Identities
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-org1.yaml --output=organizations
org1.example.com
+ res=0
Create Org2 Identities
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-org2.yaml --output=organizations
org2.example.com
+ res=0
Create Orderer Org Identities
+ cryptogen generate --config=./organizations/cryptogen/crypto-config-orderer.yaml --output=organizations
+ res=0
Generate CCP files for Org1 and Org2
/run/media/jonas/DATA/hyperledger/network with couchdb/fabric-samples/bin/configtxgen
Generating Orderer Genesis block
+ configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -channelID system-channel -outputBlock ./system-genesis-block/genesis.block
2020-12-19 22:35:49.942 CET [common.tools.configtxgen] main -> INFO 001 Loading configuration
2020-12-19 22:35:49.949 CET [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 002 orderer type: etcdraft
2020-12-19 22:35:49.949 CET [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] completeInitialization -> INFO 003 Orderer.EtcdRaft.Options unset, setting to tick_interval:"500ms" election_tick:10 heartbeat_tick:1 max_inflight_blocks:5 snapshot_interval_size:16777216 
2020-12-19 22:35:49.949 CET [common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 004 Loaded configuration: /run/media/jonas/DATA/hyperledger/network with couchdb/fabric-samples/test-network/configtx/configtx.yaml
2020-12-19 22:35:49.958 CET [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 005 Generating genesis block
2020-12-19 22:35:49.958 CET [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 006 Creating system channel genesis block
2020-12-19 22:35:49.958 CET [common.tools.configtxgen] doOutputBlock -> INFO 007 Writing genesis block
+ res=0
Creating network "net_test" with the default driver
Creating volume "net_orderer.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org1.example.com" with default driver
Creating volume "net_peer0.org2.example.com" with default driver
Creating peer0.org2.example.com ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Creating orderer.example.com    ... done
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                              NAMES
75af3bf30961        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp             peer0.org1.example.com
c01a523aebf2        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           1 second ago        Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp             orderer.example.com
6cc15482999b        hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   1 second ago        Up Less than a second   7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp   peer0.org2.example.com
```

Comment: This post helped me to find the username and password for the couchdb. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the solution to my problem by using the -s flag with the ./network.sh up command.

```
/network.sh up -s couchdb
```

I'm not sure if this is the intendet way of starting CouchDB or if it should start automatically when defining it as the default state database in the core.yaml file. But this definitly solves my problem.

Comment: what is the username and password for the couchdb? where can be found?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.3/couchdb_as_state_database.html:

```
The database cannot be converted at a later time.
```

Comment: Probably I answered to early. Are you trying to change the database for already running Hyperledger containers or you change the configuration and start everything from scratch?

Comment: I stopped the network and then changed to couchdb and started it again but it's still using leveldb after the restart.